# setState also changes screen props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have a big problem. I have screen which receive some props from another screen, I pass those props into component in thath screen via `<TicketDiaryHour {...this.props} />`. I set those props in component into my state in method **componentDidMount()**.

In that component (TicketDiaryHour) I also have flatlist. My problem is that I change data in flatlist (via setState) and props is also changing...I don't know why this happens.

My componentDidUpdate() returns prevProps == this.props and also prevState == this.state. I don't know why...

Look:

```
Prev props: {"navigation":{"state":{"params":{"props":{"id":"418103","headingText":"Klavir","roomText":"Mala dvorana","student":"Ives Berlovčnik","apsent":"1/1","startTime":"07:00","endTime":"07:30","finished":"0","listOfStudents":[{"nameLastname":"Ives Berlovčnik","id":"43275","checked":false,"o":true,"n":false}],"minutes":"30","notes":"","lesson":""}}}

This props: {"navigation":{"state":{"params":{"props":{"id":"418103","headingText":"Klavir","roomText":"Mala dvorana","student":"Ives Berlovčnik","apsent":"1/1","startTime":"07:00","endTime":"07:30","finished":"0","listOfStudents":[{"nameLastname":"Ives Berlovčnik","id":"43275","checked":false,"o":true,"n":false}],"minutes":"30","notes":"","lesson":""}}}
```

Component code:
Flatlist;

```
<FlatList
                                    ref={(list) => this.myList = list}
                                    style={[styles.flatList,{height: this.state.height}]}
                                    data={this.state.data}
                                    scrollEnabled = {this.state.showList ? true : false}

                                    contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 15 }}
                                    renderItem={({ item }) => (

                                          <View style={styles.listItemStyle}>
                                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 7, }}>

                                                {
                                                    item.checked && 
                                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                                        onPress={this.changeCheckedToFalse.bind(this,item)}>
                                                        <View style={styles.checked} /> 
                                                    </TouchableOpacity> || 
                                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                                        onPress={this.changeCheckedToTrue.bind(this,item)}>
                                                        <View style={styles.unchecked} />
                                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                                }


                                                <Text style={{color: '#000', opacity: 0.6}}>{item.nameLastname}</Text>
                                                {
                                                    item.checked &&
                                                    <View style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0 }}>
                                                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} >
                                                        {
                                                            item.o &&
                                                            <TouchableOpacity 
                                                                style={[styles.touchable1Ch,styles.iconStyle1]} 
                                                                onPress={this.changeSelectionO.bind(this,item)}>

                                                                <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 18, alignSelf: 'center' }}>O</Text>
                                                            </TouchableOpacity> ||
                                                            <TouchableOpacity 
                                                                style={[styles.touchable1,styles.iconStyle1]} 
                                                                onPress={this.changeSelectionO.bind(this,item)}>

                                                                <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 15, alignSelf: 'center' }}>O</Text>
                                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                                        }
                                                        {
                                                            item.n &&
                                                            <TouchableOpacity 
                                                                style={[styles.touchable2Ch,styles.iconStyle1]} 
                                                                onPress={this.changeSelectionN.bind(this,item)}>
                                                                <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 18, alignSelf: 'center' }}>N</Text>
                                                            </TouchableOpacity> ||
                                                            <TouchableOpacity 
                                                                style={[styles.touchable2,styles.iconStyle1]}
                                                                onPress={this.changeSelectionN.bind(this,item)}>
                                                                <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 15, alignSelf: 'center' }}>N</Text>
                                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                                        }




                                                        </View>
                                                    </View>
                                                }
                                            </View>
                                            {
                                                this.props.navigation.state.params.props.listOfStudents !== undefined && this.props.navigation.state.params.props.listOfStudents.length >= 2 ?
                                                <View style={styles.line} /> : <Text></Text>
                                            }

                                          </View>



                                    )}
                                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                                />
```

How I load data in thath component:

```
componentDidMount() {



        this.setState({
            data: this.props.navigation.state.params.props.listOfStudents,
            textOpombe: this.props.navigation.state.params.props.notes,
            textVsebinaUre: this.props.navigation.state.params.props.lesson,
            finished: this.props.navigation.state.params.props.finished,
            absent: parseInt(this.props.navigation.state.params.props.apsent.substring(0,1)),
        });
}
```

How I change data in flatlist;

```
changeCheckedToFalse = (item) => {
      console.log('Item');
        var arr = this.state.data;

        var indexOfItem = arr.indexOf(item);
        arr[indexOfItem].checked = false;
        var abs = this.state.absent;
        abs -= 1;
        this.setState({
            data: arr,
            //scrollingParent: false,
            //scrollingChild: true,
            absent: abs,
        });

          console.log('State after changing: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
    }
```

And final code; When change flatlist item, this method is trigerred

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
          console.log('Prev props: ' + JSON.stringify(prevProps));
          console.log('This props: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props));

          console.log('Prev state: ' + JSON.stringify(prevState));
}
```

Comment: AFAIK setState() triggers a render, right? If you don't want it to happen you should write your own version of componentShouldUpdate(nextProps, nextState).

Comment: Also nextProps and nextState is the same as this.props and this.state...

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're actually mutating `this.state.data` / `this.props.navigation.state.params.props.listOfStudents` - as they are the same.

I presume you're including this line: `var arr = this.state.data;` in an effort to copy the value in `this.state.data`, but I'm afraid it doesn't work like that for reference types (such as arrays). `arr` actually points to the exact same array as `this.state.data` and `this.state.data` points to the exact same array as `this.props...listOfStudents`

So when you change a value: `arr[indexOfItem].checked = false;` you are actually mutating the props.

One of the very important rules of React is "don't mutate anything", so how would you go about fixing this?

The easiest way would be to properly copy the array before changing it:

Using the spread operator
`var arr = [...this.state.data];`

Or the `Array.prototype.slice` method
`var arr = this.state.data.slice()`

**Edit**: While the above is true and would fix your issue if you had an array of primitives, you actually have an array of object references, these have the same exact issue as described above.

Copying the array doesn't copy the objects inside, only references to those objects, so you have the same issue. Try a deep copy of the array:

```
var arr = this.state.data.map(x => ({...x}));
```

Or alternatively only copy the object you're changing:

```
var arr = [...this.state.data];
var indexOfItem = arr.indexOf(item);

arr[indexOfItem] = {...item, checked: false};
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try :)

Comment: I try to implement  var arr = [...this.state.data]; but It seems like not working as I expected...It's stays the same as it previous

Comment: Btw, when I change other state my props is not changing...Only If I change flatlist which uses this.state.data for datasource...

Comment: Yeah it is mutating, If I print data in method where I change some data I get: 
Even before I setState i already see some new state.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say the props have changed? The prevProps and this.props that you specified in your question are the same. When you use the setState method, the component is updated, triggering the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method to run. It doesn't mean that your props have changed.

Comment: My props is changed...I console.log it and saw that I also changed my props for this screen, even though I only changed state...